# Function returning boolean only returns false

Tags: php, function, validation

I've a simple function that apprently puts me up with a lot of trouble. The function is:

```
function valid_mail($email) {
    $atpointers = strstr($email, "@");
    $spacepointers = count(explode(" ", $email));
    $dotpointers = strstr($email, ".");
    $ltpointers = strstr($email, "<");
    $gtpointers = strstr($email, ">");
    $illegalpts = $ltpointers + $gtpointers;
    if($atpointers >= 2 || $dotpointers == 0 || strlen($email) <= 6 || $illegalpts >= 1) { return false; } else { return true; }
}
```

And calling it in the context:

```
if(valid_mail($email) === false) { // Code } else { // Code }
```

The problem is apparently it only returns false. Any ideas for why this happens ?

Comment: `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` could replace this whole stuff.

Comment: inside the function `$atpointers = strstr($email, "@"); echo $atpointers,'<br />';` and see what it returns and you will have the answer why it returns false.

Comment: You can look at the documentation too http://php.net/manual/es/function.strstr.php

Answer (score -1):

strstr returns a substr of the string being checked, not a length. Use strpos instead.